# How can I get my hashrate and stats from my mining pool?

Tags: hashrate, mining-pools

How can I grab from monero pool my own hashrate speed? its dynamic page so I need some help:) I would like to create my own chart for my speed of hashrate when is up or down. Any idea?

Comment: This seems like a question for some web programming forum, rather then Monero.

Comment: I disagree. It's monero specific. Or at least monero pool mining specific. But it also is tough to answer any more thoroughly than I did below :-/

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to your pools config file ../config.js
   i.e. moneropool.com/config.js
2. Get the your pools api variable:  var api="https://api.moneropool.com"
   i.e. api.moneropool.com
3. to get pool stats add "/stats" to the api url
   i.e. api.moneropool.com/stats
4. to get your stats add "/stats_address" and send parameters longpool and address 
   i.e. https://api.moneropool.com/stats_address?longpool=false&address=YOURADDRESS

Answer (score 1):

If you are mining on a pool that uses the node-cryptonote-pool software, the pool uses a publicly available API. So you could do the same. Here's where the call happens: https://github.com/zone117x/node-cryptonote-pool/blob/da62fd8393434baa74260c6f085456730073444d/website_example/pages/home.html#L374

You would need to set `api` and `address` to your pool and address. Most pools have a `config.js` file like this one: https://moneropool.com/config.js. That file shows your pool's api address.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Kinda probably we did not understand a little. I do not have my own pool. I'm using a public pool mineXMR.com :) I just want to get the data about my private hashrate and use it for their own needs to do a chart. The data is dynamic so hard for me to download them in real time. Unfortunately, I am not a coder :( I'm looking for a simple solution. Get data -> export to txt or csv file -> own graph

Comment: First, you don't need your own pool. My answer is for people using any pool. AFAIK, there is no "export" feature. I'm not even sure that the pools log your hashrate over time, though they might. The only solution right now is to code your own app that monitors and stores your hashrate, or pay someone to make you one.